# How can one avoid the risks of being found carrying illegal drugs in carry on luggage whilst in transit?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage, drugs

It is often in the news, and there are stern warnings at airports: carrying illegal drugs through an airport is a bad idea.

Since I occasionally fly through Singapore, I'm always worried my carry on luggage has been unattended for hours in my previous flight. Someone could have been tampering with it.

What's the best practice to avoid the risks of being found carrying illegal drugs in carry on luggage whilst in transit?

Comment: Why are you leaving your carry on luggage unattended?

Comment: @MJeffryes Because I sleep during the flight

Comment: So your concern is that a fellow passenger is going to slip drugs into your bag in the middle of the flight? Honestly, I think this is pretty far fetched. Why would they do it?

Comment: Lock your luggage.

Comment: @MJeffryes So a confederate will pickpocket it back out of the bag on the other side of customs.  It avoids the risk of carrying it through customs.  It's not an unheard-of threat.

Comment: For a fellow passenger to slip illegal drugs into your luggage, first they'd have to have illegal drugs on the flight.  How did they get them there?  And what purpose could they possibly have to put their illegal drugs in your luggage?  All the security is _before_ boarding the flight, not _after_.  There's no point in sneaking drugs into your bags when you're already on board.

Comment: @Kyralessa Why should airport security care? From a security point of view, drugs are allowed in hand luggage.

Comment: @Kyralessa it's about getting them past *customs* at the destination, not airport security.

Comment: This question is about illegal stuff, and so we cannot/should not answer. We risk our future travel visa, and possibly also locally. A similar question about "high valuable stuffs" is instead answerable, and probably the answers could be applicable to your case.

Comment: I can see not wanting to get caught at customs, but then what does the drug-stasher do after that?  "Hey, dude, stop for a second.  I need to get something out of your luggage."  This scenario makes no sense to me.

Comment: Drug gangs keep control / over-watch on their valuable consignments. They control their couriers through fear/love/intimidation. They don't hand-off their investment to random strangers in the hope of getting it back. Drugs gangs use 'minders' to watch over their goods whether a courier on a flight or a 40ft container on a vessel.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi No, this question is about how to *avoid* getting into illegal stuff innocently as an unsuspecting traveller who has *no intention* of doing illegal things. That is a question that we can (and should) answer.

Comment: @Kyralessa oh I fully agree that this isn't a meaningful risk that OP actually needs to concern themselves with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having carry on that you can lock so that no one can open it and slip things into your luggage you are avoiding this plain and simple.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of drugs needed to make smuggling worthwhile is pretty significant — as in, you’d-notice-it significant. Drug mules are cheap and disposable so doing anything elaborate isn’t really worth it. As long as you the innocent traveler keep your bags zipped up and locked and you don’t accept unknown packages, you should be good. Remember, trying to slip something surreptitiously into someone’s bag before customs and then retrieve it safely after customs is very high risk for little reward when a mule is cheaper, can carry more, and won’t go straight to the police (or trash can) if they discover a strange package in their backpack.

The way “innocent travelers” usually get caught up is that they travel to some drug source country for holidays and while there, they strike up a friendship or romance with a local.

On return, the local asks them to bring something back to their home country — a present for some family there. At the airport, they are given a suitcase or roll-on full of “presents” but told not to look inside so as to not spoil the fun.

At customs, “fun” ensues.

Especially if it’s at Dubai or Singapore, where their security agents and judiciary  are especially “fun” people.

Comment: I think the use of the word 'fun' here is misplaced, certainly where it is used for the Dubai or Singapore part of the answer. (Many people do not get the snarky remark.)